# Save Node to another file xml Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I have a XML file:

```
<Root>
     <Lv1>
          <1_Data_Lv2_1>A1</1_Data_Lv2_1>
          <2_Data_Lv2_1>A2</2_Data_Lv2_1>
     </Lv1>
     <Lv1>
          <1_Data_Lv2_1>B1</1_Data_Lv2_1>
          <2_Data_Lv2_1>B2</2_Data_Lv2_1>
     </Lv1>
</Root>
```

**C#**

```
using (var myStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Settings.xml", FileMode.Open, myIsolatedStorage))
{
    xdoc = XDocument.Load(myStream);
} 

var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Elements("Root")
           select new
           {
               Children = lv1.Descendants("Lv1")
           };

foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
{
    foreach (var lv2 in lv1.Children)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(lv2.Value));
    }
}
```

How can i get All Node lv1 of <1_Data_Lv2_1> == "A1" and write to another xml?

Comment: Please include the code you have tried that is not working. Or are you asking if someone here will write the code for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted XML is invalid as a node cannot start with a number, i.e., `1_Data_Lv2_1` should be `One_Data_Lv2_1` and `2_Data_Lv2_1` should be `Two_Data_Lv2_1`

Once you make that change, you can find all the `One_Data_Lv2_1` nodes with the value of A1:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load( myStream );
// find all descendant nodes with a value of A1
var a1s = doc.Root.Descendants( "One_Data_Lv2_1" )
                 .Where( x => x.Value == "A1" )

foreach( XElement e in a1s )
{
    Debug.WriteLine( e.Value );
}
```

To add the result of the query to a new XML document:

```
var doc2 = new XDocument();
var root = new XElement("Root");
var lvl = new XElement( "LvlNew" );
// adding the a1s collection to the lvl node
lvl.Add( a1s );
root.Add( lvl );
doc2.Add( root );
```

Which will look like:

```
<Root>
  <LvlNew>
    <One_Data_Lv2_1>A1</One_Data_Lv2_1>
  </LvlNew>
</Root>
```